# Create subpage - filter parent pages list

Tags: pages, filters, children

I have a website here with a lot of content and with the content where is necessary to create pages in hierarchy. But it is uncomfortable to go through the dropdown in the administration with a lot of pages. So my point is - in the admin at the moment i create/edit page and need to select the parent page from the list, I want to somehow filter or limit or search the list of possible parent pages. Thank you!

Comment: Reason for "-1" : Your question doesn't include enough information for us to give you a useful answer. You haven't even mentioned if you want help regarding frontend or backend. Please edit your question & include some details & i'll undo it.

Comment: sorry, the post was edited

Comment: maybe this plugin can help in page management? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help, but I have used the code on the following page to add a parent page filter to the list of pages:

http://www.finalwebsites.com/add-a-parent-pages-filter-function-your-wordpress-admin-section/

Very handy if you have a parent page for each section.

There is just one problem - it only returns the children not grandchildren etc. I am just now trying to figure out how to get it to return results at all depths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `wp_dropdown_pages`, then use the argument `exclude_tree` to exclude a parent and all of that parent's child Pages. See here for an explanation of all arguments : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages

Answer (score 0):

Found a plugin but haven't tried it: [Parent Page Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/parent-page-filter/).

The following function can show children of site-root-level pages. This is useful for many instances, but unfortunately not useful if you want to filter for children of any page that is not at site root. I don't know PHP or WP well enough to suggest how to make this work on any page, instead of site-root-level pages.

```
function fws_admin_posts_filter( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && !empty($_GET['my_parent_pages'])) {
        $query->query_vars['post_parent'] = $_GET['my_parent_pages'];
    }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'fws_admin_posts_filter' );

function admin_page_filter_parentpages() {
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page') {
        $sql = "SELECT ID, post_title FROM ".$wpdb->posts." WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_parent = 0 AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title";
        $parent_pages = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT_K);
        $select = '
            <select name="my_parent_pages">
                <option value="">Parent Pages</option>';
        $current = isset($_GET['my_parent_pages']) ? $_GET['my_parent_pages'] : '';
        foreach ($parent_pages as $page) {
            $select .= sprintf('
                <option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $page->ID, $page->ID == $current ? ' selected="selected"' : '', $page->post_title);
        }
        $select .= '
            </select>';
        echo $select;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'admin_page_filter_parentpages' );
```

---

**Source**

I assume [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90401/38365) was first attempting to link to [this page](http://www.finalwebsites.com/add-a-parent-pages-filter-function-your-wordpress-admin-section/), but the link was dead. Found live link through Google.